# Как прервать исполнение функции

Tags: python, многопоточность, функции

Допустим у меня есть функция func, которая слушает ответ от сервера.

Я хочу сделать так чтобы допустим если эта функция выполнялась дольше секунды, то прервать ее исполнение, это прерывание я хочу реализовать в отдельном потоке

Вопрос: как мне это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call